# Overwriting rest-auth RegisterSerializer, add age validation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to validate age for user during creation by rest-auth. I managed to add field and save it during registration, but now I'm having hard time to validate if age is < 18. 
Someone could point me at the way I should do it?
I have tried with validation through my `AbstractUser` model, with `@property` method, and it was raising `ValidationError` during registration, but the User account was saving anyway, and i couldn't access to user detail view because of the `ValidationError`, so I came to the conclusion that I would just prefer to prevent registration through validation, but it isn't working in my case.

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(
        max_length=get_username_max_length(),
        min_length=allauth_settings.USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH,
        required=allauth_settings.USERNAME_REQUIRED
    )
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=allauth_settings.EMAIL_REQUIRED)
    date_of_birthday = serializers.DateField() ### ADDED BY ME
    password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def validate_username(self, username):
        username = get_adapter().clean_username(username)
        return username

    def validate_email(self, email):
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        if allauth_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
            if email and email_address_exists(email):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    _("A user is already registered with this e-mail address."))
        return email

    def validate_age(self, date_of_birthday): ### ADDED BY ME
        age = relativedelta(datetime.now(), date_of_birthday).years

        if age < 18:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Must be at least 18 years old to register.')
        else:
            return age

    def validate_password1(self, password):
        return get_adapter().clean_password(password)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password1'] != data['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(_("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return data

    def custom_signup(self, request, user):
        pass

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
            'date_of_birthday': self.validated_data.get('date_of_birthday', ''), ### ADDED BY ME
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', '')
        }

    def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        self.custom_signup(request, user)
        setup_user_email(request, user, [])
        user.date_of_birth = self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birthday') ### ADDED BY ME
        user.save() ### ADDED BY ME
        return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validated serializer fields by defining methods prefixing `validate_` to the field name. In your case, replace `validate_age` with `validate_date_of_birthday`

```
def validate_date_of_birthday(self, date_of_birthday):
    age = relativedelta(datetime.now(), date_of_birthday).years

    if age < 18:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Must be at least 18 years old to register.')
    else:
        return date_of_birthday
```